# Dynamically change transform-origin for a scale in jquery after drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on an page that contains a rectangular inner-block inside a container. The inner-block can be dragged and also be scaled when you scroll the mouse.

[ [See my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z2aQ2/54/). ]

The center of the screen is the origin point of the zoom transformation, so when the inner-block is centered in the page it appears to simply scale, but when you drag the inner-block about the center origin point, it will scale appropriately around or away from the center point of the screen. I marked the center screen point with a small red dot in the JSFiddle so its easier to see.

As the inner-block is dragged around I recalculate the top/left coords of it, and also the difference between that position and the center of the page in order to get the transformation-origin adjustment coords.

**PROBLEM**: It works fine when the inner-block is scale-factor 1, but if you zoom and then drag the object, it unexpectedly jumps position and doesn't zoom back correctly. Are you able to see what I am doing wrong, or what I would need to add to prevent the unexpected behavior? Thanks in advance!

```
//Get center of the page "origin"
var originX = $('.block').width()/2;
var originY = $('.block').height()/2;

//Get center point of the inner-block
var blockRX = $('.inner-block').width()/2;
var blockRY = $('.inner-block').height()/2;

//Set position of the inner-block to match center origin initially
$(".inner-block").css({top: originY-blockRY, left: originX-blockRX});
$(".inner-block").draggable();

//Initial Scale 1:1
var scale_system = 1;

//Get Top/Left coords of inner-block
var blockTop = $('.inner-block').offset().top;
var blockLeft = $('.inner-block').offset().left;

//Calculate diff between center of page and Top/Left of inner-block
var xCalc = (originX-blockLeft);
var yCalc = (originY-blockTop);

//Set origin of transformations as center of page (in relation to Top/Left)
//Using the just calculated values
$(".inner-block").css({"-webkit-transform-origin": xCalc+"px "+yCalc+"px"});

//Zoom settings
var maxScale = 4;
var minScale = 1;
var zoomScale = .07;

//Drag Actions
$(function() {
    var isDragging = false;

    //Perform calculations as drag occurs
    $(".inner-block").mousedown(function() {
        $('.inner-block').mousemove(function(e) {
            isDragging = true;
            $(window).unbind("mousemove");

            //Get New Top/Left of inner-block as it drags
            blockTop = $('.inner-block').offset().top;
            blockLeft = $('.inner-block').offset().left;
            console.log("BlockTopLeft "+blockLeft+" "+blockTop);

            //Calculate new diff between Top/Left and Origin
            xCalc = (originX-blockLeft);
            yCalc = (originY-blockTop);
            console.log("Origin Distance "+xCalc+" "+yCalc);
            })
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        var wasDragging = isDragging;
        isDragging = false;
        $(window).unbind("mousemove");
        if (wasDragging) {
            //Update origin position in relation to Top/Left of inner-block
            $(".inner-block").css({"-webkit-transform-origin": xCalc+"px "+yCalc+"px"});
        }
    });
});

//Perform scroll function below on mousewheel
$('.block').bind('mousewheel', function (event) {
    scroll(event);
});

function scroll(event) {

    event.preventDefault();  

    var newScale = ((event.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) ? 
                    (scale_system * (1.0 + zoomScale)) : 
                    (scale_system * (1.0 - zoomScale)));

    scale_system = ((newScale > maxScale) ? 
                    (maxScale) : 
                    (((newScale < minScale)?
                      (minScale):
                      (newScale)))
                   );

    //Update Top/Left position of the inner-block
    blockTop = $('.inner-block').offset().top;
    blockLeft = $('.inner-block').offset().left;
    console.log("BlockTopLeft "+blockLeft+" "+blockTop);

    //Update X/Y radius to block center
    blockRX = ($('.inner-block').width()/2)*scale_system;
    blockRY = ($('.inner-block').height()/2)*scale_system;
    console.log("BlockRXY "+blockRX+" "+blockRY);

    //Recalculate the diff between T/L and origin
    console.log("Origin "+originX+" "+originY);
    xCalc = (originX-blockLeft);
    yCalc = (originY-blockTop);
    console.log("Origin - TL "+xCalc+" "+yCalc);

    $(".inner-block").css({"-webkit-transform": "scale(" + scale_system + ")"}); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to my own question. After much Googling it appears there are problems with jQuery when trying to perform CSS transformations paired with dragging. [There is an extensive issue page](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6844) on jQuery's development ticket page highlighting the problem and many examples, and they have decided not to address the problem. I'm going to explore other options.